# How to remove new line or line break from string in Objective-C

Tags: html, objective-c, newline, carriage-return

In browser I am getting output like

```
"post":"<p>this is for testing<\/p>\r\n",
```

but when I store this output in string it returns:

```
"post":"<p>this is for testing<\/p>",
```

and displaying it on label it extends new blank line.
How to remove blank line?

`[myMutableString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString: @""];` and all are not working.

Comment: try subStringToIndex prooerties

Comment: You probably think it isn't returning '\r\n' because they aren't "visible characters". I'm not sure about '\r', but '\n' is the skip line character. Did you tried to remove both '\r' and '\n' with `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:`?